# Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\teller\fungsi.php on line 2

Tags: php, session

i get a notice

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\teller\fungsi.php on line 2
Notice: Use of undefined constant status - assumed 'status' in C:\xampp\htdocs\teller\fungsi.php on line 17
Notice: Use of undefined constant status - assumed 'status' in C:\xampp\htdocs\teller\fungsi.php on line 20
```

in my code. I try this function in the old my sql version was success. but in my sql versi 5.5.16 it doesn't work. 
this is my source code :

```
<?php 
session_start();
function ver_user($username,$password)
{
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('teller');
    if (!empty($username)) 
        {
            $query="SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username`='$username'";
            $action=mysql_query($query);
            $data=mysql_fetch_array($action);
            $passmd5=md5($password);
            if ($data['password']==$passmd5)
                {
                    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                    $_SESSION['password']=$password;
                    if ($data[status]==1){
                        $data['0']="valid";
                    }
                    if ($data[status]==2) {
                        $data['0']="valid1";
                    }   
                    return $data;
                }
            else 
                {
                    $data['0']="invalid";
                    return $data;
                }
        }
}
function logout()
{
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this an `include` file? Are you calling `session_start()` in the script that includes it?

Comment: FYI, sql is in no way related to the notice that you're getting

Comment: oh yes I called session_start() in the script that includes it. I cleared one of them, then success. thank you

Comment: I think you are starting the session somewhere before. If you are using includes be sure that you are calling `session_start()` once

Answer (score 0):

The second and third warning are because

```
$data[status]
```

should be

```
$data['status']
```

There isn't enough information in the question to explain why you get the warning about `session_start()`. You need to check more of the code to find where you're calling `session_start()` before this.